# how to filter for an optional field

Tags: linq, ravendb

I have a Solution class:

```
public class Solution{
   public bool? IsTemplate{get;set;}
   public string createdBy{get;set;}

}
```

some documents have the IsTemplate field set to true or false, many don't have it.

How can I get the solutions that either have it set to false together with those that do not have the field at all (legacy docs)?

I've tried to filter by IsTemplate being null, false, null or false, but I never got back the solutions that do not have the IsTemplate field.
The only way I've got to work is the following, but it's ugly as hell.

```
 using (IDocumentSession session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
            {
                var ret= session.Query<Solution>().Where(x => 
                 x.createdBy.Equals(owner)) //an user's solutions
                .ToList()
                .Where(s => s.IsTemplate == null || s.IsTemplate == false)
                .ToList();
                return ret;
            }
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: OK Andreas, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an index that look at the missing property:

```
from x in docs.Solutions
select new
{
  IsTemplate = x.IsTemplate == true // if this is null, will return false
}
```

Then query on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ret = session.Query<Solution>()
     .Where(x => x.createdBy.Equals(owner)
         && (!x.IsTemplate.HasValue || x.IsTemplate.Value == false))
     .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. Only documents with IsTemplate=false are selected

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the first `ToList` is used because the `IQueryable` implementation this "document store" provides doesn't support your query for some reason, you cannot do much more.

I suggest:

- Opening a bug report with the provider to implement the required functionality, or add it yourself if you have access to the codebase.
- In the meantime, use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` so as to not buffer the entire dataset before proceeding.

The `Where` clause seems rather straightforward. If your application makes no semantic difference between the property not being present and it being false (it sounds like it in your description), I would consider mapping the absence condition to the false condition and using a destination data structure that doesn't allow a nullable `IsTemplate`.

```
        using (IDocumentSession session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Query<Solution>()
                .Where(x => x.createdBy.Equals(owner))
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(s => new {
                    IsTemplate = s.IsTemplate ?? false,
                    CreatedBy = s.CreatedBy })
                .ToList();
        }
```

Notice the resulting object is anonymous and we're returning it; that precludes us from using a well-typed method signature. Thus, I would definitely *define* another `Solution` class.

You can see the design emerge naturally: you now have two `Solution` types. One for the domain, used by the application and that doesn't care at all about legacy conditions like "IsTemplate" being null (it never is from the point of view of the application), and another that is only used to glue the legacy conditions during your transition period. Make sure to organize them and name them adequately so that it's clear which is used for what (leverage .NET namespaces, that's what they're good at!).

Comment: @everyone: The example is the same solution as the accepted answer, it also addresses the relevant buffering issue and adds explanations (especially regarding the next steps since anonymous types cannot by definition appear in sigs which will be an issue for OP since the list is returned). AFAICT the downvote was a drive-by downvote. You be the judge.